# Easy way to generate Getters and Setters in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, getter-setter

Is there a way to generate getters and setters in Visual Studio?
 I'm trying with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> and i get this:

```
public String Denomination
{
    get { return denomination; }
    set { denomination = value; }
}
```

and what I want is this:

```
public String getDenomination()
{
    return Denomination;
}

public void setDenomination(String Denomination)
{
    this.Denomination = Denomination;
}
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not really sure if there is a way to do it, but **why** do you need such thing ? Why not properties ? Properties at the back end will have similar methods as yours.

Comment: It looks like you are coming from a Java background, C# has different [naming standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) than Java. You should try and learn the new standards if you plan on working with other C# developers.

Comment: What Visual Studio is giving you is the standard format for getters/setters in C#.

Comment: Consider if `public string Denomination {get;set;}` is enough for you.

Comment: Well, this is not the standard at C# (yes, i come from Java xD).
So i can use what i got first instead of the "Java way"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `prop` code snippet to create automatic properties.

Type `prop`, and press `Tab`.  You can then change the Type and name of the property.

In your simple case, where no additional logic is required, there's no needed for backing fields.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a built in way to do it out of the box with Visual Studio, but they do provide a way for you to add that feature.

What you will need to do is create a [Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) that creates those two methods and add the snippet to your `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets` folder. Once you do that you will be able to type the snippet name in and hit `tab` and it will fill in the text you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Its merely an opinion** but I am not a big fan of properties since I began with java development and then switched to C#.

I know developers who love them and I know some who hate them but if your team for example wants to use getter and setter instead of properties then this snippet might be interesting to you.

I changed the one which generates properties to fit my needs but maybe its also right for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>getset</Title>
            <Shortcut>getset</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for Getter and Setter</Description>
            <Author>bongo</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>object type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>GSName</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Getter Setter name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyMethod</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>field</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The variable backing this Getter Setter</ToolTip>
                    <Default>myVar</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ $field$;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public void Set$GSName$($type$ value)
    {
        $field$ = value;
    }       

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public $type$ Get$GSName$()
    {
        return $field$;
    }
    $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

if you add it like Scott Chamerlain said or use the Code snippet manager of Visual studio in the Tools tab you can type *getset* and then press *tab* in Visual studio and it will generate this:

```
private int myVar;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value"></param>
public void SetMyMethod(int value)
{
    myVar = value;
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public int GetMyMethod()
{
    return myVar;
}
```