# Can I Use Insert Snippet to Create Setters and Getters in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, properties, code-snippets

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25648670/2642059) suggests creating a Code Snippet to allow the "Insert Snippet" menu to contain setters and getters in Visual C#.

I went to check out the answer's link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx

But it really doesn't have information about inserting anything more than fixed strings.

What I want is to be able to right-click on a member-variable, select "Insert Snippet", and the option for inserting a setter or getter will contextually be there. Is there a way to accomplish this in Visual C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert snippets in Visual C++, however not the way that you are wanting to.

Visual C# enables the user to add getters and setters on properties for example if I have the following property:

```
public double foo
```

If I select `foo`, it would be easy to code a snippet which would insert:

```
{ get; set; }
```

Note that there is no reuse of the name `foo`.

If I wanted to create a getter and setter in C++ I'd need to do the following:

```
double getFoo(){ return foo; }
void setFoo(double foo){ this->foo = foo; }
```

I cannot do this with snippets as of Visual Studio 2013, because I cannot use `$selected$` more than once: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171418.aspx#code

So I could write a snippet, say doubleGetSet, that inserted the code:

```
double get*(){ return *; }
void set*(double *){ this->* = *; }
```

But the inserter of snippet would have to be responsible for changing `*` to `Foo`/`foo` respectively.

However, by the time you've done that it becomes unclear why you couldn't have just typed this in the first place.

In conclusion, until `$selected$` becomes a literal so it can be reused in snippets, creating getters and setters with a snippet is not viable.